# Are newlines guaranteed to be escaped in JSON

Tags: python, json

I want a file of newline-separated JSON records. So newlines in records must be escaped.

My test strings in python are indeed escaped. But is it guaranteed across ALL JSON implementations (like Java's)?

Comment: I'm wondering on why you're using newline separated JSONs instead of the simpler option of using a JSON list containing those JSON records you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are properly escaped, you do not have to worry about different implementation as long as the implementation is compliant with [JSON Specifications](http://www.json.org/). 
Data exchange formats like XML and JSON, are meant to solve the difficulty of inter-operability. Being the simple text formats they are interpreted in a similar way across all the implementations.

XML compared to JSON provide more granular control, by letting us specify the encoding format.
However, JSON in this regard forces us to follow unicode encoding.

**NOTE:** In short, don't worry about the JSON itself, but don't forget to make use of unicode strings over standard ASCII characters (default in python <= 2.7) for that matter. 
This will ensure that JAVA interprets the string in a right way, since JAVA has unicode encoding format by default.

Answer (score 0):

Correction: I previously said the JSON specification was explicit, but it turns out that the informal JSON spec on the website is not as explicit as I had thought, and the more explicit RFC actually has a different interpretation of the term "control characters" than the unicode standard.

From the [JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7):

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the
> quotation marks, except for the characters that must be escaped:
> quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
> through U+001F).

Note that this definition of control characters is different from unicode:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/list.htm

Unicode considers characters U+007F to U+009F control characters, while the JSON RFC says they are not.

Here's a table of characters considered line-breaks in unicode:

http://www.unicode.org/standard/reports/tr13/tr13-5.html

```
      Unicode   ASCII  EBCDIC*
CR    000D      0D     0D     0D
LF    000A      0A     25     15
CRLF  000D,000A 0D,0A  0D,25  0D,15
NEL*  0085      85     15     25
VT    000B      0B     0B     0B
FF    000C      0C     0C     0C
LS    2028      n/a    n/a    n/a
PS    2029      n/a    n/a    n/a
```

Two of the newline characters, the line (U+2028) and paragraph (U+2029) separators, are *not* unicode control characters. They each belong to their own unicode category. The NEL character (U+0085) is a unicode control character but not considered a control character in JSON. All three of these can appear unescaped in a JSON string and represent themselves.

You can be very confident that any JSON library worth its salt won't include CR or LF unescaped. You should not see VT or FF unescaped either. However you will see NEL, LS and PS characters unescaped in JSON.

(I previously thought that NEL was considered a control character in JSON. On that basis I submitted this bug report to Python, where my mistake was pointed out to me: http://bugs.python.org/issue21194)

Answer (score -1):

According to the [JSON specs](http://www.json.org/):

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in
> double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.

So yes, they are escaped in all the standard compliant implementations.

Comment: Note that there are [many newline characters in Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode), so technically JSON strings may contain line breaks since JSON only tells you to escape `\n` and `\r`. In practice, however, `\r` and `\n` is all you usually get. Not my downvote, BTW.